# Multiple values for a given variable

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I have no idea how to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. I have 2 files that I am reading in : yesterday's people list and today's people list
2. I am attempting to diff these 2 lists and print out the differences in the output
3. One of the columns that I am comparing is the Supervisor for a given person yesterday and today
4. Often, there are multiple people who have all have been moved from Supervisor A to Supervisor B
5. I want to create a set whose name is SupervisorA_SupervisorB and then add the names of all the people who have moved from Supervisor A to Supervisor B, and then later print the set.
6. How do I create a variable with a dynamic name, since the Supervisor A and B could be C, D, E, etc.

---

I suspect many of you will suggest dictionaries and that is fine, but I am trying to add multiple Employees to a Old-Supervisor_New-Supervisor variable.  I'm still not clear on how to go about doing that.

---

Dynamic variables may not be the solution, and I am fine with that.  The output I'm looking for is something like this

### Sup A --> Sup B

Bill
Harry
Sally

### Sup D --> Sup C

John
Matt

### Sup N --> Sup L

Steve
Jen
Sue
Rob

So in case, there were multiple people who had a specific Supervisor change.

Comment: No to *dynamic variables*, Yes to [*dictionaries*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: "I suspect many of you will suggest dictionaries and that is fine, but I am trying to add multiple Employees to a Old-Supervisor_New-Supervisor variable. I'm still not clear on how to go about doing that." This is us telling you specifically _not_ to do that, because it's not a very good idea. Especially if you have to dynamically put the variable name together every time you access the variable, there is no good reason not to use a dictionary.

Comment: @mixingbuddha: You just need to make a dictionary where the keys are (old_supervisor, new_supervisor) tuples. Here's a simple example I just whipped up: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/22f3b363d834e2bfa818

Comment: @DanielPryden - That was awesome! Thanks so much. I'm still not sure I completely understand it, but I got it to work

Answer (score -1):

Use [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) Unordered collections of unique elements. It supports operations like union, intersection, difference... Make one for 'yesterday' and one for 'today' and apply the desired operatio.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, which is about dynamic variable names.